# Is there a way to find all matching objects in an NSArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c

If I have an NSArray object that has multiple int values (eg. @[1,5,3,8,1,1]), is there a way in Objective-C to find the indices of *all* matching objects?

For 1, given the array above, get back 1,5, and 6?

I could use a for loop, but was looking for a faster approach if it exists.

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: You'd get 0, 4, 5 back. I doubt there is a faster way than iterating through the array. If you're dealing with large arrays, you could first do a [array contains] to make sure there's at least one matching element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all indices are zero-based, so the expected indices are 0, 4, and 5.

I guess the most efficient way in ObjC is `indexesOfObjectsPassingTest`, it returns an `NSIndexSet`

```
NSArray<NSNumber *> *array = @[@1,@5,@3,@8,@1,@1];
NSIndexSet *indexSet = [array indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL(NSNumber *obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
    return [obj isEqualToNumber:@1];
}];
NSLog(@"%@", indexSet);
```

Comment: Oh yeah! Thanks so much!